# Best way of validating WCF input

Tags: wcf

In my services all the methods except certain mandatory parameters and all the input parameters are encapsulated inside message contract.

Right now, we are validating the input in each and every service method, Its like duplicating validation logic in all the service methods. Is there any way I can move all these validation to common place and more over I don't want my service method to be executed as the input is not valid.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [FluentValidator](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) for each `MessageContract` request.

You can write the commom validator for the request which have common validation rules.

**Ex**: If you want the validate employee profile in both `CreateEmployeeRequest`, `UpdateEmployeeRequest` then you can write the commom validator for Employee Profile (`EmployeeProfileValidator`) and make use of this validator in Create & Update Employee request validators..

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Library [Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) has a module for [Integration with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664526%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx).

It implements input validation as a WCF parameter inspector. Your method will never be called if it the parameters fail validation.